Unsigned int weird behavior with Loops in C
In C, I encounter this weird problem:
For the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (int j = i - 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
        printf("RUN1?\n");
    }
    
    int j = i - 1;
    int k = i + 1;
    for (; j < k; j++) {
        printf("RUN2?\n");
    }
    
    printf("DONE?");
}

The first loop did not loop (0 times) while the second loop can run 2 times. I don’t see what’s fundamentally different.
The below also works...
for (;j < (int)(i+1); j++) {}

I have seen some posts here, but did not find any good explanation.
Maybe someone can link one here?

What do you expect the result of i - 1 to be when i is an unsigned integer with value 0? (It's been too long since I've written C to know what I'd expect, but I think it's an important question...) Also, note that the comparison of j < i + 1 is (presumably) between a signed int and an unsigned int, whereas the comparison of j < k is between two signed ints...

unsigned int i = 0; -> int i = 0; and it works as you expect. computing i - 1 with a result of "-1" and saving it in a signed vs unsigned variable is the difference here.

@JonSkeet i-1 should be a very large number, but if I do int j = i - 1 and print it, it is -1...

What if you print it using %u to see what is the value as an unsigned integer? (%d or %i expect signed integers...)

What happens if you take the loop out and write int j = i - 1; if (j < i + 1) { printf("In if body"); }? Given what you've said, I expect that not to print anything. Simplifying it from "loop" to "single if condition" is helpful IMO.

@SergeBallesta You are right! Did not think the specifier makes the difference. But this still does not explain why the first loop does not work? since j should be 0 and j=0<1...

" since j should be 0" - why would j be 0? I'd expect j to be -1. My guess is that j < i + 1 is promoting the value of j to an unsigned int before performing the comparison, therefore testing "large number < 1".

oh ye, should be -1, my bad

@JonSkeet that makes sense!

Enable your compiler's warnings. You should have gotten some. With gcc, I use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

The difference between the 2 loops is in the types used for the condition:

In the 1st loop the condition is: j < i + 1. Since i is unsigned (and so is i+1) j is also converted to unsigned to perform the comparison. As an unsigned it is a high number and never < i+1.
In the 2nd loop the condition is j < k. These are both signed values and therefore they are not converted to unsigned. j is initialized to -1 when i-1 is converted to signed int. The result is the one you expected (2 iterations of the loop).

Your compiler should warn you about this issue.
E.g. MSVC issues the following warning for the condition in the first loop:
warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch

Note:
When the unsigned i-1 is converted to signed you get an overflow. The result is implementation defined. A common result (which you also get) is -1 but it is not guaranteed.

So when doing comparison, C automatically convert int to unsigned int first? not unsigned int to int? Or is the order I write it matters (so 1st type is converted into the 2nd type)

Yes, the C language rules are that when both signed and unsigned values are compared the signed is converted to unsigned (and not the opposite). The same happens e.g. when you add a signed and unsigned value.

Okay, thank you so much! Got it now!

Note also that when i-1 is converted to signed, you get an overflow and the result is implementation-dependent. On most implementations this will be -1, but it's not guaranteed.

@Barmar good point - added a note.

@WilliamLi That's why you shall raise the warning level to the maximum. Good compilers will warn you about such mixed comparisons. And then use a zero-warnings-zero-errors policy.
